# how to store output html to an var in php?

Tags: php

how to store output html to an var in php ?

how to set `$a = require(xx.php)?`
the xx.php outputs html , i want to store this html to a var , how to do?
please see my codes bellow:

a.php codes:

```
<?php
    // a.php
    echo 'hello world';
?>
```

b.php

```
<pre>
<?php
    ob_start();
    $a=require('a.php');
    ob_clean();
    echo $a;    // get '1' but not 'hello world'

    // can not post , why?
    // can not post , why?
    // can not post , why?
    // can not post , why?
    // can not post , why?
    // can not post , why?

?>
```

Comment: `require` and `include` don't RETURN what you required/includes. They only return the STATUS of the operation, e.g. a true/false indication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the "require" is not what you want. Try:

```
ob_start();
require('a.php');
$a = ob_get_clean();
echo $a;
```

Comment: Pretty sure we answered at the *exact* same time.

Answer (score 3):

You're after [`ob_get_clean()`](https://www.php.net/ob_get_clean):

```
$a = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use shell_exec

```
<?php

    $out = shell_exec("php -s $File");   
?>
```

see: http://php.net/shell_exec

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to your case you want output of any PHP page which you want to use in your current page in that case you need to use CURL in PHP

```
    $ch = curl_init('a.php');

    $htmlResponse = curl_exec($ch); 
                curl_close($ch);

echo $htmlResponse ;
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I got the answer.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require('a.php');
    $a=ob_get_clean();
    echo $a;    // get '1' but not 'hello world'


?>
```